# move audio strips from blender vse to audacity

Tags: transforms, audio

I need to move audio strips from blender vse into audacity. I am just learning how to use audacity, so I would welcome explicit instructions.
The audio strips were recorded with the video, but under different circumstances, and so they need work to make them the same quality.
I am using blender 2.83, windows 10 on a pc. The strips are mp4, ffmpeg.
I have downloaded ffmpeg.

Comment: Audacity will open audio tracks from mp4, then you can save them out as mp3 or wav for importing back into Blender. The original video's audio strip can be deleted

Comment: My problem is, How do I move them into audacity? I tried dragging them, but that doesn't work. where would I find the file for each strip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not already rendered the strips to a file, do that first.

If you have, or when you do, the file will appear in the directory you selected in the Properties editor *Output Properties* tab in the *Output section*.  It will have a name like *0001-0nnn.mp4* where 'nnn' is replaced by the number of frames you have specified.

Now open Audacity.  Use the *File → Open* menu to navigate to the directory you specified and open the mp4 file.   Audacity will ignore the video and place the audio strips into the editor.

The shortcut to render the file is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>F12</kbd>

Here are the settings you should adjust before you render.  You find them in the *Properties Editor* in the output tab.

[image: Properties editor showing settings for rendering an MP4 with MP3 audio]

From Top to Bottom:

The folder where you will find the output file.  The file will have a name like *0001-0nnn.mp4* where 'nnn' is replaced by the number of frames you output.

The file format.  Set this to *FFMPeg Video*.  The other settings will not show up until you do.

The container format.  Set this to MP4. The audio Code settings won't show up until you do.

The audio Codec.  Set this to mp3. The audio pane may be closed.  Click on the arrow at the left of "Audio" to open it, if it is.

To find out more about the settings you can read the [Render Output Format](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/format.html) section of the manual.

The other two settings you will probably want to adjust are the start and end frames.  Set the end frame to the length, in frames, of your VSE strips.